# VS 2010 C++/CLI .NET how find text from string with REGEX

Tags: regex, c++-cli

I want to get a part from string with `regex_search` in VS 2010 C++.

Here is my current code that does not work:

```
String ^ str = "www.MyWeb.com/457812/now-tommorow.html";
String ^ what = "([0-9]+)\\/.*.html";
String ^ result;

Regex ^ r = gcnew Regex(what);
result = r->Match(str)->Value;
```

My result output is: **/457812**

I want that my result output **SHOULD BE** like this: `result = "457812/now-tommorow.html";`

Could anyone tell me why this does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you are trying to assign a `Match` object to a `String` variable, and you cannot instantiate a `regex_search` native function as a managed object.

Here is a sample code with the fixes that returns `457812`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String ^ str = "www.MyWeb.com/457812/now-tommorow.html";
    String ^ what = "([0-9]+)";
    String ^ result;
    Regex ^ r = gcnew Regex(what, System::Text::RegularExpressions::RegexOptions::CultureInvariant);
    result = r->Match(str)->Value;
    Console::WriteLine(result);
    Console::Read();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can find some more examples on the [MSDN portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4384yce9.aspx).

Comment: The solution is correct but the failure reason not quite so... He's using `gcnew` on `std::regex_search` (which means he's trying to *instantiate a native function as a managed object*, which just doesn't make any sense to the compiler).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Yes, true, I was so focused on the code that forgot to add to the explanation :) The answer is updated.

Comment: Yes, but how everything (result from regex) put to string? Because i don't need only value.

Comment: @xPossible:  The question is put on hold because you did not specify what exactly you want. In most cases with regexes, we are interested in the value matched. What are you interested in? Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: I'm interested in that: example my string = "www.MyWeb.com/457812/now-tommorow.html"; with regex i want find text not only numbers, i want get example : result from regex = "457812/now-";

Comment: If you need to also get the substring from the number up to the first hyphen, you can use another regex: `"[0-9]+[^-]*[-]"` or `"([0-9]+)/([^-]*[-])"`. See example: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5d%2b%5b%5e-%5d*%5b-%5d&i=www.MyWeb.com%2f457812%2fnow-tommorow.html

Comment: could you look up, i edited my first topic, then you understand what i want :/

Comment: Your regex (must be a bit corrected to `([0-9]+)\\/.*\\.html`) yields `457812/now-tommorow.html` match value. Please also check on regexstorm.net. (The link is not pasting well.)